# a plugin is needed to display this content (svg)

Tags: svg

I have a program return svg data, Chrome & Firefox complain "a plugin is needed to display this content". I used Fiddler to trace the http response and save the data as svg file. Chrome/Firefox can display the svg file. But Chrome/Firefox does not display during http response with xml format for svg data. Is my svg header missing something?

SVG Data as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" height="595">

<defs>
<marker refY="5" refX="10" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" orient="auto" markerWidth="10" id="rarrow" markerHeight="10">
<path d="M0 0 10 5 0 10z" fill="black"/>
</marker>
<marker refY="5" refX="0" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" orient="auto" markerWidth="10" id="larrow" markerHeight="10">
<path d="M0 5 10 10 10 0z" fill="black"/>
</marker>

<linearGradient y2="100%" spreadMethod="pad" y1="0%" x2="0%" x1="0%" id="LG_V_GreenWhite">
   <stop style="stop-color:#99FFCC" offset="0%"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:white" offset="100%"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient y2="100%" spreadMethod="pad" y1="0%" x2="0%" x1="0%" id="LG_V_WhiteGreen">
   <stop style="stop-color:white" offset="0%"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#99FFCC" offset="100%"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient y2="0%" spreadMethod="pad" y1="0%" x2="100%" x1="0%" id="LG_H_RedWhite">
   <stop style="stop-color:#FFAEAE" offset="0%"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:white" offset="100%"/>
</linearGradient>
<svg:style type="text/css">
<![CDATA[       
.hint  { font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; stroke: none; fill: grey; }
.hint-area { stroke-width: 1pt; stroke:blue; fill:none; fill:#ffefd3; border :1px; border-style :solid; padding :1; height :14px; width :14px; border-color :#336699;}

@font-face{font-family:'Helvetica';src:url(map_h.cef)}
@font-face{font-family:'CaflischScript-Bold';src:url(map_c.cef)}
]]>
</svg:style>
</defs>

<g id="backlayer"/>
<rect y="30" x="110" height="40" class="party-ext" width="150"/><text y="50" x="185" class="party-title">10.34.160.23:5061</text><text y="62" x="185" class="party-name">601</text><line y1="70" x2="185" x1="185" y2="545" class="timeline"/><rect y="30" x="290" height="40" class="party-int" width="150"/><text y="50" x="365" class="party-title">10.34.160.23:5060</text><text y="62" x="365" class="party-name">SIPServer</text><line y1="70" x2="365" x1="365" y2="545" class="timeline"/><rect y="30" x="470" height="40" class="party-ext" width="150"/><text y="50" x="545" class="party-title">127.0.0.1:5070</text><text y="62" x="545" class="party-name">501</text><line y1="70" x2="545" x1="545" y2="545" class="timeline"/>
<text y="120" x="83" class="time-txt">20140410-170252.083  [1]</text><line y2="120" marker-end="url(#rarrow)" x2="365" y1="120" x1="185" class="party-link"/><text y="115" x="275" class="rq">INVITE sip:501@CA-L02577.na.frs</text><text y="145" x="83" class="time-txt">.083  [2]</text><line y2="145" marker-start="url(#larrow)" x2="365" y1="145" x1="185" class="party-link"/><text y="140" x="275" class="r1">100 Trying</text><text y="170" x="83" class="time-txt">.084  [3]</text><line y2="170" marker-start="url(#larrow)" x2="365" y1="170" x1="185" class="party-link"/><text y="165" x="275" class="r4">401 Unauthorized</text><text y="195" x="83" class="time-txt">.087  [4]</text><line y2="195" marker-end="url(#rarrow)" x2="365" y1="195" x1="185" class="party-link"/><text y="190" x="275" class="rq">ACK sip:501@CA-L02577.na.frs</text><text y="220" x="83" class="time-txt">.087  [5]</text><line y2="220" marker-end="url(#rarrow)" x2="365" y1="220" x1="185" class="party-link"/><text y="215" x="275" class="rq">INVITE sip:501@CA-L02577.na.frs</text><text y="245" x="83" class="time-txt">.088  [6]</text><line y2="245" marker-start="url(#larrow)" x2="365" y1="245" x1="185" class="party-link"/><text y="240" x="275" class="r1">100 Trying</text><text y="270" x="83" class="time-txt">.095 [7]</text><line y2="270" marker-start="url(#larrow)" x2="365" y1="270" x1="545" class="party-link"/><text y="265" x="455" class="rq">INVITE sip:501@127.0.0.1:5070</text><text y="295" x="83" class="time-txt">.098 [8]</text><line y2="295" marker-end="url(#rarrow)" x2="365" y1="295" x1="545" class="party-link"/><text y="290" x="455" class="r1">100 Trying</text><text y="320" x="83" class="time-txt">.123 [9]</text><line y2="320" marker-end="url(#rarrow)" x2="365" y1="320" x1="545" class="party-link"/><text y="315" x="455" class="r1">180 Ringing</text><text y="345" x="83" class="time-txt">.124  [10]</text><line y2="345" marker-start="url(#larrow)" x2="365" y1="345" x1="185" class="party-link"/><text y="340" x="275" class="r1">180 Ringing</text><text y="370" x="83" class="time-txt">.125 [11]</text><line y2="370" marker-end="url(#rarrow)" x2="365" y1="370" x1="545" class="party-link"/><text y="365" x="455" class="r2">200 OK</text><text y="395" x="83" class="time-txt">.126  [12]</text><line y2="395" marker-start="url(#larrow)" x2="365" y1="395" x1="185" class="party-link"/><text y="390" x="275" class="r2">200 OK</text><text y="420" x="83" class="time-txt">.127  [13]</text><line y2="420" marker-end="url(#rarrow)" x2="365" y1="420" x1="185" class="party-link"/><text y="415" x="275" class="rq">ACK sip:501@10.34.160.23:5060;transport=udp</text><text y="445" x="83" class="time-txt">.127 [14]</text><line y2="445" marker-start="url(#larrow)" x2="365" y1="445" x1="545" class="party-link"/><text y="440" x="455" class="rq">ACK sip:501@127.0.0.1:5070;user=phone;transport=udp</text><text y="470" x="83" class="time-txt">20140410-170256.213  [15]</text><line y2="470" marker-end="url(#rarrow)" x2="365" y1="470" x1="185" class="party-link"/><text y="465" x="275" class="rq">BYE sip:501@10.34.160.23:5060;transport=udp</text><text y="495" x="83" class="time-txt">.214  [16]</text><line y2="495" marker-start="url(#larrow)" x2="365" y1="495" x1="185" class="party-link"/><text y="490" x="275" class="r2">200 OK</text><text y="520" x="83" class="time-txt">.214 [17]</text><line y2="520" marker-start="url(#larrow)" x2="365" y1="520" x1="545" class="party-link"/><text y="515" x="455" class="rq">BYE sip:501@127.0.0.1:5070;user=phone;transport=udp</text><text y="545" x="83" class="time-txt">.216 [18]</text><line y2="545" marker-end="url(#rarrow)" x2="365" y1="545" x1="545" class="party-link"/><text y="540" x="455" class="r2">200 OK</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: It seems missing header during posting:  
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" height="595">

<defs>
    <marker refY="5" refX="10" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" orient="auto" markerWidth="10" id="rarrow" markerHeight="10">
    <path d="M0 0 10 5 0 10z" fill="black"/>
    </marker>

Comment: Both browsers can definitely display svg graphics without a plugin. Most likely you send some strange headers (or none at all) indicating to the browser what content type to expect.

Answer (score 0):

As arkascha suggested, check the MIME type (Content-type) that the web server is sending back with the SVG file.  You can see what it is in the Firebug "Network" tab.  It should be "image/svg+xml".  If it is not, you will need to adjust the web server configuration.